# Preprocessor definitions based on visual studio configuration type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, preprocessor

I am working on a C++ project in Visual Studio 2019, which should have the ability to be compiled as an executable and as a DLL. It is legacy code and contains the preprocessor flags AS_EXE and AS_DLL, which is presumably the flags I need to set. I just don't know how to do this based on different values in Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type. I would like the values Dynamic Library (.dll) and Application (.exe) to map to the two preprocessor definitions, AS_DLL and AS_EXE respectively.

I have looked around on Google the last couple of days, but without luck.

It would be nice if it could be done similarly to when switching between debug and release, but I sense that it'll be a bit more complex. Can this even be achieved? And if so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: You can `#define` things on the compiler commandline, too. This is similar to the debug/release switch.

Comment: Not sure what you actually asking for ,but the Compiler properties and Linker properties have a commandline property where you can view the full commandline parameters

Comment: @engf-010 I am asking how to pass AS_DLL/AS_EXE depending on which options is set in the project's properties. It can probably be done in the code, but it would be nicest to have visual studio pass the preprocessor definitions itself. Something like "if ConfigType == dll /D "AS_DLL" else /D "AS_EXE" (pseudocode ofc)

Comment: This document may help: [Microsoft-specific predefined macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(_DLL)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170#microsoft-specific-predefined-macros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Condition` attribute of `ItemDefinitionGroup` node in your `.vcxproj`.

```xml
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='MyConfigForDLL'">
  <ClCompile>
    <PreprocessorDefinitions>AS_DLL;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    ...
  </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='MyConfigForEXE'">
  <ClCompile>
    <PreprocessorDefinitions>AS_EXE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    ...
  </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Or, from GUI:[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately, I can't upvote due to my account being new though :(